# AngularFire createUser example not working outside of Firebase website

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

In an attempt to learn AngularFire, I've been messing around with AngularFire user authentication methods. On the Firebase website, an example is given that, when I plug in my Firebase address in the proper place, works. When I copy and paste the code into Notepad++ and attempt to run it that way, the HTML works, but none of the Javascript does. I added an alert box to the Javascript, and on opening the page, the alert box popped up, but none of the rest of the JS worked. I feel like I'm missing something very obvious. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help!

My code is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.0.0/angularfire.min.js">    </script>    
</head>
<body>
<script>
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", ["firebase"]);

        // let's create a re-usable factory that generates the $firebaseAuth instance
    app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
      function($firebaseAuth) {
        var ref = new Firebase("https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/?page=Auth");
        return $firebaseAuth(ref);
      }
    ]);

    // and use it in our controller
    app.controller("SampleCtrl", ["$scope", "Auth",
      function($scope, Auth) {
        $scope.createUser = function() {
          $scope.message = null;
          $scope.error = null;

          Auth.$createUser({
            email: $scope.email,
            password: $scope.password
          }).then(function(userData) {
            $scope.message = "User created with uid: " + userData.uid;
          }).catch(function(error) {
            $scope.error = error;
          });
        };

        $scope.removeUser = function() {
          $scope.message = null;
          $scope.error = null;

          Auth.$removeUser({
            email: $scope.email,
            password: $scope.password
          }).then(function() {
            $scope.message = "User removed";
          }).catch(function(error) {
            $scope.error = error;
          });
        };
      }
    ]);
  </script>
      <div ng-app="sampleApp" ng-controller="SampleCtrl">
               Email: <input type="text" ng-model="email">
               Password: <input type="text" ng-model="password">

  <br><br>

  <button ng-click="createUser()">Create User</button>

  <br><br>

  <button ng-click="removeUser()">Remove User</button>

  <p ng-if="message">Message: <strong>{{ message }}</strong></p>
  <p ng-if="error">Error: <strong>{{ error }}</strong></p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what has happened is that you have used the ng-app directive twice in your html.  If you look at the [Angular documentation for ng-app](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/directive/ngApp), the first ng-app tag is auto bootstrapped as an application, any additional ng-app have to be manually loaded.  Also, you cannot nest applications in a page.  When I tried to run your application the SampleCtrl controller is undefined.

I've removed the first ng-app directive and the rest of your code seems to work fine in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vq7kCXoHkBUVlwlONQop?p=preview) I've created.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
ng-app directive is already delclared in the body, removing this one
<html ng-app>
-->

<html>

<head>
...
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="sampleApp" ng-controller="SampleCtrl">
  ...
</body>
</html>
```